# Sorting List<Map<String, Object>>

Tags: java, sorting, collections

I am having the below object

```
List<Map<String, Object>> listMap = new ArrayList<Map<String, Object>>();
```

How do i sort this based on the value `("Object")` in the Map?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Create your own [`Comparator`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.6/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html) and use it .

```
List<Map<String, Object>> listMap = new ArrayList<Map<String, Object>>();
Collections.sort(listMap,new Comparator<Map<String, Object>>() {

            public int compare(Map<String, Object> o1, Map<String, Object> o2) {
                //your logic goes here
            }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Use your own Comparator (You have to implement the given interface)

Answer (score 1):

One of the easiest ways to solve using Java 8 is :

```
Collections.sort(listMap, Comparator.comparing(map -> (String)map.get("key")));
```

Or,

```
listMap = listMap.stream().sorted(Comparator.comparing(map -> (String)map.get("key"))).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Note: I have converted key(Object) into String. You can use as per your requirements.